# Spring Boot Mail send email using acces token

Tags: spring, spring-boot, jakarta-mail

I have simple mail sending functionality in project which configured in one bean.

```
@Bean
public JavaMailSender javaMailSender() {
    JavaMailSenderImpl javaMailSender = new JavaMailSenderImpl();

    Properties properties = new Properties();
    properties.setProperty("mail.smtp.auth", "false");
    properties.setProperty("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", "465");
    properties.setProperty("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class", "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");
    properties.setProperty("smtp.socketFactory.fallback", "false");
    properties.setProperty("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
    properties.setProperty("mail.smtp.starttls.required", "true");

    javaMailSender.setHost("smtp.gmail.com");
    javaMailSender.setProtocol("smtp");
    javaMailSender.setUsername("username");
    javaMailSender.setPassword("password");
    javaMailSender.setJavaMailProperties(properties);

    return javaMailSender;
}
```

and it works great.

Now I want to add functionality for sending emails via accessToken/refreshToken of specific email.

How to do it? What should I extend in my bean or add another bean for sending with token? I couldn't find some example which is full explained. As I understand I should add `setFrom()` and in `setPassword()` put accessToken

Comment: If the token is a JWT(I assume), then you can do it by adding a password claim in the token then decoding it and retrieving the password and move forward. There is no other way I believe you can do it since `JavaMail` has `password` property but no token verfication property

Comment: @Anas access/refresh tokens are given by OAuth2 protocol. When user tries to authenticate gmail account my server getting authorization code and then I exchange for refresh/access token.

Comment: Check the answer by bill, it has connecting to javamail through oauth access token

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The use of [OAUTH2 with JavaMail is explained on the JavaMail project page](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/OAuth2).

Also, you should fix these [common mistakes](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/FAQ#commonmistakes) in your code.

Comment: Good answer, it helped me.

Comment: Is it good to hold opening one session when application is started and then don't close until application will be shutdown for different emails? Because now it opens session inside method and sending, after finishing as I understand it closes session and it will be so every time.

Comment: A JavaMail Session can be long lived, but a Transport or Store that has been connected to a server will keep open a network socket connection, which might be an issue.  And the server can close the connection at any time, so you need to be prepared to handle that.